# Form submission is refreshing the page in React

Tags: reactjs

```
const DataSendHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const data = eventctx.eventData()
  let formData = new FormData()

  for (const property in data) {
    formData.append(property, data[property])
  }

  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}` },
    body: formData
  };

  try {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/createEvent', requestOptions)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data))
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
}

return(
  <form onSubmit={(e) => { DataSendHandler(e) }} >
    <Form.Group controlId="formFile" className="mb-3">
      <Form.Label>choose a relevant picture for your Event to show customer</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control type="file" onChange={picHandler} />
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group controlId="picture" className="mb-3">
      <Form.Label>picture </Form.Label>
      <Form.Control type="file" multiple onChange={docHandler} />
    </Form.Group>
    <div className={classes.np}>
      <Button className={classes.button} onClick={props.previousStep}>
        privious
      </Button>
      <Button className={classes.button} onClick={doneHandler}>
        Done
      </Button>
      <Button type="submit" className={classes.button} disabled={btndisable}>
        Submit
      </Button>
    </div>
  </form>
)
```

Comment: I would assume some of your JS is breaking which is causing `e.preventDefault()` to not work. If you use the 'Preserve Log' option on Chrome DevTools (assuming you're using Chrome), the JS error will still be displayed in the console after the page has refreshed, and you should be able to go from there.

Comment: hi, Thanks for help I am able to communicate with my backend but there is no such error for the e.preventDefault()